# Get the current song information from volume control (command, etc)

Tags: command-line, nuvola

I was wondering if there's a way to get the current song in Elementary OS from the volume menu item.

[image: Screenshot of volume]

So, is there a command I can use to get it, or detect when the song changes? I'm essentially trying to write a program that automatically runs a script whenever the song changes (or just updates occasionally) with my current song.

I'm using the Nuvola Player

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indicator is using the MPRIS dbus interface. So you could listen to dbus.
For example something like this.

```
dbus-monitor --session "path=/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2" --monitor | awk '
  /string  *"xesam:artist/{
    while (1) {
      getline line
      if (line ~ /string "/){
        sub(/.*string "/, "artist:", line)
        sub(/".*$/, "", line)
        print line
        break
      }
    }
  }
  /string  *"xesam:title/{
    while (1) {
      getline line
      if (line ~ /string "/){
        sub(/.*string "/, "title:", line)
        sub(/".*$/, "", line)
        print line
        break
      }
    }
  }
'
```